# Android PdfRenderer Bitmap Image distorted after saving to Storage

Tags: java, android, pdf, bitmap, opengl-es

So basically i'm using PdfRenderer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer to make a bitmap of a specific page of pdf. Image look fine when shown in `ImageView`. But distorted when saved on the device. (Basically i'm saving the bitmap for debugging purpose. It's also appearing distorted when when i use `Canvas drawBitmap()` Method)

***Method that create Bitmap.***

```
public Bitmap pdfToBitmap(Context context, File pdfFile, int pageNumber) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {

            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));

            PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(pageNumber);

            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

            page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

            page.close();

            renderer.close();


        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return bitmap;

    }
```

***Using the above method***

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        PdfUtility pdfUtility = new PdfUtility();

        File source = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/Book.pdf");

        if (source.exists()) {

            final Bitmap bitmap = pdfUtility.pdfToBitmap(MainActivity.this, source, 9);

            Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Size" + bitmap.getByteCount());

            BitmapUtility.saveBitmapToGallery(this, bitmap, "Pages");

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
```

***Method that save Bitmap***

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + folder);

            boolean isDirectoryExisted = directory.exists();

            if (!isDirectoryExisted) {

                isDirectoryExisted = directory.mkdir();

            }

            if (isDirectoryExisted) {

                File imageFile = new File(directory + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

                try {

                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

                    fileOutputStream.flush();

                    fileOutputStream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);

                mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

                context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            }
```

***Image shown in ImageView vs Saved on Device***

[image]
[image]

Comment: it doesn't looks like distorted ... rather like it has transparent background ... which is natural as printers doesn't use white paint to draw background an you choose to render it for print

Comment: also you should obviously use page width and height not device metrics

Comment: @Selvin i tested it with other option too ```PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY```

Comment: @Selvin i think both are outputting transparent background. Can you tell what i can do to remove transparency? So that i can check if it's the issue of transparency or something else.

Comment: @Selvin thank you. Fixed the issue by adding these lines in ```pdfToBitmap()``` method  ```Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);```